# Options for multi level TLS certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, x509

Below a brain dump of the problem I am facing and solutions I have found so far. I am looking forward to your input!

**Use Case**
I am looking to expose different services at different subdomains, while also encoding several stages in the host name.
That would result in something like

- service1.dev.company.tld
- service2.dev.company.tld

I can also imagine giving individual teams more flexibility and dedicating an entire domain tree to them, that would then be

- whatever1.whatever2.project.company.tld

This is particularly nice, because I might even delegate management of these trees via NS/SOA records.

To my understanding, this requirement is commonly referred to as *multi-level subdomains*.
I've done some research and found some solutions, however none really seems to fully capture what I want. So specifically I am looking for the following:

- some input into whether or not I assess the options at hand correctly
- some rationale into why something I am actually looking for  does not currently exist on the market.

**Solution Approaches**

- **multi-domain (SAN) certificates**
  ... covering SANS like  `hard-coded1.dev.company.tld, hardßcoded2.dev.company.tld`.

  - if combined with wildcard SANs, scales with the number of stages, so reasonably well.
  - allows max. 1 deep layer. That severly hampers how teams can work with it downstream.
  - needs to be regenerated/re-requested whenever anything changes.
- **Private PKI**

  - Use of custom Root CA that signs an intermediate that

    - has CA=true in its basic constraints
    - uses the X509 nameConstraints extension to limit certificate generation to *.dev.company.tld
  - scales to whatever I want, fairly easy to implement
  - is private, so I would need to ask everyone to trust said Root CA.
    ... this cannot be expected of everybody, in particular not external parties I deal with
- **Let's Encrypt style ACME**

  - will validate specific domains on-the-fly as long as I can show ownership
  - doesn't cost anything
  - requires me to have infra in place to perform certificate request, ownership validation and certificate provisioning automatically
  - does not (?) allow me to stick additional info on the cert/ go for OV level certificates

    - Organisation/Department Info

To me, the  *Private PKI* approach would seem to be the most natural one; however, as mentioned, I  cannot expect third parties to support this solution. I already implemented that solution for internal systems. Ideally, I would like to have this solution, but with public trust. Unfortunately I cannot seem to find a Root CA that is willing to dole out intermediates with the given permissions, specifically the combination of name constraints and CA=true (why is that, actually?).

This leaves me to the ACME certificates that I can get for free with Let's Encrypt. While this is definitely going to work just fine from a technical perspective (and I have seen that in the wild), I somehow consider Let's Encrypt to be more of a "a real certificate would be too expensive" option. That is probably just a bias on my side, because I see it more often on sites that didn't have the budget to get it from a paid CA.

I *could* also live happily ever after, if I were to regenerate wildcard SAN certificates from public vendors for free.
So let's say I get myself a wildcard SAN certificate for a list of (sub)domains. Then I wouldn't want to pay whenever I need to add a new SAN to the certificate. If I demonstrate ownership of the second level domain and pay once, I would expect to be able to (re)request said certificate as often as I like. If a vendor offers this, it would also fully satisfy my need.
However, I cannot pay a hundred bucks every single time I need to add a new SAN.

That was my quick brain dump; thank you in advanced for your input!

Comment: The option you don't seem to consider is that you back down from your multilevel subdomain idea since it complicates certificates too much. For now the only explanation I can extract from your question is that it would be *"particularly nice"*. And you also ask *"why something I am actually looking for does not currently exist on the market"* w/o considering that others might have chosen different ways to approach what you want to do with multilevel domains.

Comment: @steffen-ullrich 
We went ahead and implemented that (using ACME automation for each "layer" we need). I am happy to say that it works just fine. :)